# How do I convert PHP JSON to JS array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Good day,

I have this data which I got from my query on PHP its is currently a JSON Format, now I want to convert it into array so I can use it on my pdf. How can I do this?

so in order for me to use it on my javascript I used

```
var inventory = <?php echo json_encode($inventory); ?> ;
```

my JSON data :

```
var inv = [
{"xid":96,"xitem":"CARBOCISTEINE 500MG CAP (MYREX) BOX",
"itemId":852,
"price":3,
"mprice":3
 },
{"xid":253,"xitem":"CIPROFLOXACIN 500MG TAB (PROSELOC\/FLAMINGO)",
 "itemId":1165,
 "price":0,
 "mprice":0
 }];
```

I tried

```
var rows = <?php echo json_encode($inventory); ?> ;
var arr = $.map(rows, function(el) { return el; });
```

and

when I `console.log(arr);`
I still get the object structure not the array structure that I wanted.

I also tried

```
var result = [];

for(var i in rows)
    result.push([i, rows [i]]);

console.log(result);
```

but it gives me

```
[ ["0",Object { xid=96,xitem="CARBOCISTEINE 500MG CAP (MYREX) BOX",itemId=852,price=3,mprice=3}],
["1",Object{etc..}]];
```

instead

I want it to have a structure like

`[96,"CARBOCISTEINE 500MG CAP (MYREX) BOX",852,3,3],
 [253,"CIPROFLOXACIN 500MG TAB (PROSELOC\/FLAMINGO)",1165,0,0]`

Is there something I am missing on my code or How should I be able to do this? thanks..

Comment: when you `json_decode` in php, it already creates an array, so would be just easier to create what you want to do in php instead of javascript

Comment: you should search for "how to convert javascript object to array"

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys.. my keyword is wrong all this time xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var arr = inv.map(function (obj) {  return [obj.xid, obj.xitem, obj.itemId, obj.price, obj.mprice]})
console.log(arr);
```

If you do small changes to your map callback function, then it will be fine.

Comment: This is what Im Trying to achieve.. Thanks sir @Beroza Paul

Answer (score 0):

you can do just

```
class MyClass
{
    public $var1 = 'value 1';
    public $var2 = 'value 2';
    public $var3 = 'value 3';
}

$class = new MyClass();
$arr = [];

foreach($class as $key => $value) {
    $arr[] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($arr); //here's to check
```

in PHP - you can make a collection of object like this and iterate first oveer this collection to get result as you wanted to have

Comment: Thanks for the answer mr @m.antkowicz but Im already using my php's json structure for my view, and size would be doubled if I pass another Array structure on my view for my script.. thats why I just wanted to convert the existing variable with object structure into another variable with array structure in it.. hope i make sense.. thanks for the effort too..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to hard code the keys. The following works:

```
var arrayFromObject = inv.map(function (item) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var p in item) arr.push(item[p])
    return arr;
});
```